# My harddisk isn't detected?

Tags: hard-drive, boot

My harddisk started making this sound and doesn't work anymore. Can anyone help me here?  I have tried removing and attaching the hard drive, but nothing seems to work and I can't even boot into my computer now.

https://www2.zippyshare.com/v/LdMbnH3C/file.html

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hard drives that 'make noises' are soon to be hard drives that no longer work at all.

Replace the drive & recover the data from your backup.
If no backup, then you will need to find a data recovery service.
Expect to pay somewhere between $100 & $1000.

Answer (score 0):

Based your description, the hard disk makes sound, it may be hardware problem of this hard disk(hard disk head or hard disk motor...). It is recommended to detect hard disk hardware through professional maintenance department. Maybe you will backup the data in this bad hard disk ,then repair the bad hard disk or change a new hard disk, reinstall operation system if needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use https://drevitalize.com/current/drev332d.zip and make a DOS bootable USB and run it. It will make a mirror HDD of your old HDD to your new HDD by copying all the raw data to the target drive. Then boot using the new HDD, all your data including OS will be in the new HDD.